# Can Voyager 1 reach the Andromeda Galaxy?

Tags: artificial-satellite, interstellar-travel

Right now, as of 2021, *[Voyager 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1)* has left the Solar System. If it has reached such a great distance, is it possible for it to reach the [Andromeda Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda_Galaxy)? Also, will we be able to still be in contact with Voyager 1 in case it reaches the Andromeda Galaxy?

Comment: If Voyager 1 won't go to Andromeda, Andromeda must come to Voyager 1. Which in fact it will.

Comment: It's funny, I have to upvote both answers, one with 'yes', the other with 'no'. Both are correct.

Comment: Leaving the Solar System is "such a great distance" only if you compare it to going down the road to the chemist's. But if you compare it to the distance between galaxies, even neighboring ones, it's just peanuts.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1189/).

Comment: vsz's is [from HHGTTG](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dwz3XLVxXac&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=9&t=0m28s) (only paraphrased, though). Preceded by *"[Space, it says, is big, really big.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dwz3XLVxXac&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFUOPyA8aLONTz5jr-IQFu5&index=9&t=0m19s)"*

Comment: Distance aside, Voyager 1 would also need to be headed *towards* the Andromeda Galaxy (which does not encircle the Milky Way, so unlike Rome, not all roads lead to it.)

Comment: Just to add to some comments here, and based on what I've read elsewhere, Voyager 1 is heading towards the constellation of Camelopardalis. It's kinda roughly in the same part of the night-sky as Andromeda, but still way, way off. So even if the escape velocity discussion wasn't relevant (it is!), Voyager 1 wouldn't get to the Andromeda galaxy!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

### Technically, yes

While Voyager 1 lacks the velocity necessary to escape the Milky Way galaxy, it doesn't actually need to.  [Because the Milky Way galaxy itself will collide and begin to merge with the Andromeda galaxy within about 4.5 billion years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andromeda%E2%80%93Milky_Way_collision).  It's unlikely any objects within either galaxy will collide with something in the other.  But it's pretty likely a lot of dust and some stars will get ejected from them, which could even conceivably include the Voyager spacecraft itself (or even our own Sun).

This is many billions of years longer than the projected lifespan of Voyager's batteries, however.  And it is within a billion years or so of the projected lifespan of our own sun, at which point Earth's surface is expected to be too hot to have liquid water.  So we would not be able to communicate with it due to lack of battery, and also not being able to exist any more (short of settling other worlds, possibly other star systems).  However, [some modelling suggests that the Voyager craft, and indeed their golden records, may still be meaningfully intact by the time of the merger/collision](https://www.space.com/predicting-voyager-golden-records-distant-future).

Comment: But would Voyager 1 itself still exist after about 4.5 billion years?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin exist is a tenuous concept. Neither matter nor energy can actually be created or destroyed, it just changes form. So in that sense, yes, Voyager 1 will still exist. Of course, not even a *good* lab will be able to positively identify even one atom of its material, but that does not mean it won't *exist* (tl;dr: no. it will run into something, get blown up, eaten by a star, or recycled by Watto the Toydarian's Deep Space Salvage Junkers, a long, *long* time before then.)

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin The only thing to threaten the craft is dust.  Which definitely isn't meaningless over these timescales, but the golden disks they carry were designed to last a billion years or more in space in the worst case scenarios for dust encounters.  [Here's an article covering research that suggests the records would be at least partially intact and readable for some 5 billion years, enough for the merger/collision to begin](https://www.space.com/predicting-voyager-golden-records-distant-future).

Comment: This answer is [technically correct, the best kind of correct.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ZEuWJ4muYc)

Comment: Semantically correct is best, which this is not, because the new galaxy formed will need a name.

Comment: @Mazura I believe the accepted name is "Milkdromeda"

Comment: @Mazura The merger does not happen at the same time as the first collision.  They will circle about and collide multiple times before they settle into a single galaxy.

Comment: Technically it may not be correct. 4.5 billion years might be a time of closest approach, but the Galaxy centres could be separated by as much as 50-100 kpc at that time, and merger may not occur for 10 billion years or more.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy nice! I was really just asking, I wasn't claiming that it was likely that the craft would not exist.

Comment: @ProfRob True.  The linked article ends with some fanciful-sounding speculation that if things go just right (basically, the craft being ejected from the merging combo early) it could be meaningfully intact for trillions of years.  But once they start merging it really depends on how dust gets distributed around wherever the craft ends up being.  And with bad luck it might not be meaningfully intact for long. How close counts as good enough depends on what region we're calling "Andromeda galaxy", anyway; are we including diffuse dark matter and dust halos, etc.

Answer (score 76):

## no.

Voyager 1 is currently orbiting the center of the Milky Way, which has an escape velocity of $550 \ \text{km}\ \text{s}^{-1}$ at the Sun's position, while the Sun orbits at $\sim 220 \ \text{km}\ \text{s}^{-1}$. Voyager was ejected at $\sim 17 \ \text{km}\ \text{s}^{-1}$, like @user438383 said in a comment, and in the prograde direction, which means, at best, Voyager 1 will be traveling at $237 \ \text{km}\ \text{s}^{-1}$, which is $313 \ \text{km}\ \text{s}^{-1}$ short of ejection, so it cannot escape toward the Andromeda galaxy.

Comment: ... and even if we ignored that - it would need 3.3 billion years for the journey at the current distance. And that's just 3,299,999,980 years after the power supply ran out.

Comment: And a good argument can be made that the slow pounding of CBR will have reduced it to slag by then.

Comment: Humm... I wonder how many gravity assists from stars would be needed for it to reach galactic escape velocity?

Comment: Note that 17 km/s is approximately c/17635. So at that speed it takes around 17,635 years to go 1 light-year.

Comment: Well, it could get *lucky* and get one or more [gravity assists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) from (sufficiently cold) massive objects, in order to achieve galactic escape velocity. That also allows it to change direction. After all, it couldn't have achieved Solar System escape velocity without gravity assists.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I saw your recent edit and wanted to comment on your comments; 1) "There isn't any need to declare a question" perhaps not in that case in that way, but I generally reiterate my question title or an expanded form at or near the end of longer question posts. I have developed this habit over time, after too many random "What is your actual question?" comments by folks who didn't really read through. Repetition is a useful tool when writing for a wide and diverse reader base and it has completely stopped the  "What is your actual question?" comments.

Comment: @PeterMortensen so while it was probably a good edit in that case, please don't start in on the now literally thousands of instances of me repeating the question at or near the ends of my question posts network-wide. *Thanks!* 2) Not all links need to be dressed and there are several good reasons to leave some bare. Again in that case maybe it was helpful, and I often do, but I certainly have many *intentionally* bare links and hope nobody goes and starts dressing them all up! 3) It's great that you add those helpful links to English SE! :-)

Comment: @PeterMortensen sorry to comment here; I think it will be a while before your edit there will be accepted and you don't have any Q or A posts here in Space SE, so in a pinch I've pinged you here. I can clean this up as soon as I get a ping back.

Answer (score 4):

As already answered, the Voyager spacecraft (both 1 & 2) lack the velocity required to escape the Milky Way (assuming either is even headed in the right direction), so would only encounter Andromeda when the two galaxies merge in several billion years. As of this writing, the two spacecraft have been operating for some 44 years; there is a limit to how much longer their RTGs can provide adequate power for even the most minimal of spacecraft operations. According to a NASA FAQ [here](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/frequently-asked-questions/), it appears unlikely that radio contact can be maintained beyond about 2036. By that time, they will technically still be within our solar system (well inside the [Oort cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud)), thus still far closer to the Sun and the Earth than the distance to even the nearest neighbor star.